Rauch filter design
SE long time no posts, here is my question, i want to find the transfer function of this circuit:
So i considered the impedances in the feedback as one feedback impedance
\$\frac{1}{Z} = pC_3 + \frac{1}{R_6 + \frac{1}{pC_2}} = \frac{pC_3(R_6C_2p +1)+pC_2}{R_6 C_2p+1}\$
Thus : \$Z = \frac{R_6 C_2 p +1}{R_6C_2 C_3 p^2 + (C_2+C_3) p }\$
thus : \$ \frac{V_s}{V_e} = - \frac{Z}{R_5} \$
I feel like this isnt valid, please correct me!

Have you looked up band pass MFB filters?

can you have a look at what i did in proof @Andyaka

Your attempt fails. The feedback is not through a single impedance because the feedback network has 3 terminals. A single impedance has 2 terminals. Here's how to get it right:

Write node voltage equations for nodes A and B. Assume the circuit and the opamp work, so the opamp forces the voltage of node B to 0 volts. The opamp input doesn't drag any remarkable current, let it also be zero in the equations.
Eliminate the voltage of node A and solve the ratio of the input and output voltages. That's the transfer function.
This method has 2 traps: It assumes the circuit is stable and the opamp input current is negligible.
ADD you can convert delta-circuit C2C3R6 to star and use then your original idea, but the conversion is so complex that I wouldn't call the idea brilliant, no matter one of the branches is redundant (=worth of a wire) due the zero opamp input current.

R6 & C2 are in series, thus the combined impedance is in parallel with C3, no? Are you suggesting that $\frac{1}{Z} = (C_2 + C_3)p + \frac{1}{R_6+\frac{1}{pC_2}}$

infinite thanks, but i dont want to go through the traditional method of KVL, i would like a fast brilliant way, if you could pin point what i did wrong or try to correct it would be great to accept as an answer, but regardless i had your answer upvoted.

It's fatal error to use the same idea how one calculates the gain of the inverting opamp amplifier gain. The feedback and the input are mixed in more complex circuit. Nobody never can show anything finer analyse for your failure. You need voltages of node A and node B. Or you can build the equations for current loops. Converting the delta circuit C2C3R6 to star helps assuming the opamp input doesn't drag current, but the complexity if the conversion eliminates all of the brilliance. But in that way your original idea will work.

Infinite thanks but last question please, why would i benefit from the conversion of delta to star? i want to find the equivalent impedance in that mesh though.

No equivalent impedance exists, because the circuit C2C3R6 has 3 separate terminals. An impedance can have only 2. Nobody ever finds the non-existent thing you dream of. Conversion to star changes the topology to the same as the topology of the inverting opamp amplifier.

Great, thats the part i didnt know of, infinite thanks.

@ HellBoy - just a short recommemdation: When designing the filter you can select two equal capacitors. This makes the calculation somewhat easier.
